# Are smooth curves under a diffeomorphism smooth curves?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, curves

Recently, I was reading a proof about showing the tangent space of a smooth manifold, and I was struggling in understand this:

> Let $\phi$ be a diffeomorphism, then $\phi$ induces a bijection between smooth curves in $U$ (open in $\mathbb{R}^n$) and smooth curves in $\phi(U)$.

I think this is because diffeomorphism is a bijection such that it preserves the geometric structure between two sets. Am I correct?

Comment: Definition of diffeomorphisms requires both $\phi$ and $\phi^{-1}$ be differentiable.

Comment: @astro The point I am struggling is that, must the diffeomorphism of a curve be a curve? If that is the case, then if the curve is smooth, the mapped curve is also smooth since diffeo.

Comment: The image of a curve under a continuous map is a curve. That's obvious.

Comment: A curve in $U$ is just a continuous map $\gamma:[0,1]\to U$. Since diffeomorphisms are continuous, $\phi\circ\gamma:[0,1]\to\phi(U)$ is also continuous, and thus a curve in $\phi(U)$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! @Vercassivelaunos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A smooth curve is (typically) a smooth map $f:[0,1]\to U$. And so if $\varphi:U\to V$ is a diffeomorphism then our smooth curve induces a smooth curve $g:I\to V$ given by the composition $g:=\varphi\circ f$. And so $f\mapsto \varphi\circ f$ is a function between sets of smooth curves with the inverse $g\mapsto \varphi^{-1}\circ g$. That's most likely what the author meant.